# как сконвертировать 2 байта hex Buffer в int

Tags: javascript

есть вот такой буфер hex-значений - fe ff 03 99 00 01

мне нужны последние 2 байта - достаю их так

```
buf.slice(4,6)
```

получаю буфер 00 01

как преобразовать их к int что бы получилось 1?

а в случае если бы было 1A 17 получить 6679 и тд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У класса [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) есть специальный API для чтения данных. В вашем случае отлично подходит метод [Buffer.prototype.readUInt16BE](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_readuint16be_offset_noassert):

```
var b1 = Buffer.from([0xfe, 0xff, 0x03, 0x99, 0x00, 0x01]);
console.log(b1.readUInt16BE(4)); // 1

var b2 = Buffer.from([0xfe, 0xff, 0x03, 0x99, 0x1A, 0x17]);
console.log(b2.readUInt16BE(4)); // 6679
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать метод [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) для конвертации строки в число , только необходимо, чтобы пробелов не было в строке (к примеру так - `"0001"` корректно, а так `"00 01"` - нет).

Пример конвертирования `hex` в `int`:

```js
var hexOne = '0001';
var hexTwo = '1A17';

var one = parseInt(hexOne, 16);
var two = parseInt(hexTwo, 16);

console.log(one);
console.log(two);
```

Массив в строку можно конвертировать разными способами, к примеру через [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) вот так:

```js
var arr = ['1A', '17']; // массив
var hexStr = arr.join(''); // получаем строку `1A17`
var number = parseInt(hexStr, 16); // конвертируем строку в число
console.log(number); // выводим в консоль результат
```